# Google Sheets - Indicate which cells sum a value

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

Sometimes we have customers that, when they pay their EOM account, they pay more or fewer invoices than needed and do not provide a remittance. This makes figuring out which invoices they've paid difficult/time-consuming.

I'm looking for a formula or script that will, for example, look through column A (invoice values) and then highlight or place an X in column B next to the ones that add up to (or closest without going over) a total invoice value in cell C2.

I've been trying to work this out, but nothing is working...

[image: Example of set up]

Comment: your example is insufficient. pls extend it

Comment: Hi there - in what way is it insufficient? Please explain what additional information you need. Thank you!

Comment: for example, it's unclear why the X is on 95,9 and 54,5. how did you figure it out? also is C2 valid for the whole A column?

Comment: C2 is the total value I am looking for. I manually worked out that 95.5 and 54.5 are the only combinations in the list that equal 150 and manually added to Xs to indicate this.

Comment: I'm looking for a formula or script that will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So if C2 is going to be constant, (all rows) you could use a vlookup to find the difference of $A and $C$2.....
Wrapped in an IF to print X if found.....
Wrapped in an IFERROR to remove the #n/as...
So I got

=IFERROR( IF($A2+( VLOOKUP ($C$2-$A2:$A:5,1,false))=$C$2, "X", " "))

And someone smarter than me could probably wrap that in an array formula, but it will work with autofill.